# How to fetch this Json using Volley in Android

Tags: android, json, facebook, android-volley

i'm trying to fetch this Json of facebook page photos:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/233713473419953/photos/uploaded/?fields=images%2Ccreated_time%2Cname%2Calbum&access_token=1792039221044098%7CAUTDDgGHH8Tzfz_RTrIGnaOTer8

Using Volley with this code:

```
 private void fetchImages() {

    pDialog.setMessage("Carregando Fotos...");
    pDialog.show();

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    pDialog.hide();

                    images.clear();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Image image = new Image();

                            JSONObject album = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            image.setName(album.getString("name"));

                            JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("images");
                            image.setSmall(url.getString("source"));
                            image.setMedium(url.getString("source"));
                            image.setLarge(url.getString("source"));
                            image.setTimestamp(url.getString("created_time"));

                            images.add(image);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(PhotosActivity.this, "Erro ao carregar as fotos!! Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }


                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

But, i don't know why this not working, Look my error log:

```
E/PhotosActivity: Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"data":[{"images":[{"height":1080,"source":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/t31.0-8\/15025513_559017034222927_9118471543496511523_o.jpg","width":1080},{"height":960,"source":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/15134703_559017034222927_9118471543496511523_n.jpg?oh=13ff804fb169acfd7ce920b838307094&oe=58BEEE0C","width":960},{"height":720,"source":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/p720x720\/15134703_559017034222927_9118471543496511523_n.jpg?oh=8b464f6f0cea6c0cf5f43143a2a52d6f&oe=58CB047D","width":720},{"height":600,"source":"https:\/\/fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net\/h-ak-xft1\/v\/t1.0-0\/p600x600\/15134703_559017034222927_9118471543496511523_n.jpg?oh=a0cf471c3983fa1ed6be76e80ef5b4b1&oe=58BD1257&__gda__=1490108287_654543542cb382e20b8ccf22c53fc940","width":600},{"height":480,"source":"https:\/\/fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net\/h-ak-xft1\/v\/t1.0-0\/p480x480\/15134703_559017034222927_9118471543496511523_n.jpg?oh=dd7df79fe92bb542b91f65c2a78edaad&oe=58C393B7&__gda__=1489225631_ae3d0517c84a89b98c70a2ade8d454f3","width":480},{"height":320,"source":"https:\/\/fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net\/h-ak-xft1\/v\/t1.0-0\/p320x320\/15134703_559017034222927_9118471543496511523_n.jpg?oh=f65125e4e9098e36d494a5ca0596cdc6&oe=588B1EED&__gda__=1489373637_8c9ed6992b75d119dce4dbb82d1b3fee","width":320},{"height":540,"source":"https:\/\/fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net\/h-ak-xft1\/v\/t1.0-0\/p180x540\/15134703_559017034222927_9118471543496511523_n.jpg?oh=a605e018bb94850ccb4f61721387f09e&oe=58D3DC50&__gda__=1490253944_5d04db9710cf69f5f8a34bd1d8f1ecb5","width":540},{"height":130,"source":"https:\/\/fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net\/h-ak-xft1\/v\/t1.0-0\/p130x130\/15134703_559017034222927_9118471543496511523_n.jpg?oh=3d31ffdccabd8eb2cef549841e03983b&oe=58D57382&__gda__=1490237354_5ac451bf19bee0665e43ba4bc35bd0f1","width":130},{"height":225,"source":"https:\/\/fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net\/h-ak-xft1\/v\/t1.0-0\/p75x225\/15134703_559017034222927_9118471543496511523_n.jpg?oh=279e3dd5f02d74f3b92b97209e1c511f&oe=588835F6&__gda__=1488842348_baff2cb6c9d6661503a346c279bf30eb","width":225}],"created_time":"2016-11-16T18:50:09+0000","name":"#Quinta é dia da mulherada se encontrar no #LugarDeNovosComeços a partir das 15h para crescer em Deus, para compartilhar, para fazer novas amizades!!! Então não fica de fora! Convida suas amigas e vem pra cá!\n.\n.\n.\n#LagoinhaNiteroi #MulheresLagoinhaNiteroi #VemPraCa #VemPraJesus #Experimenta","album":{"created_time":"2013-06-04T22:08:15+0000","name":"Timeline Photos","id":"233720070085960"},"id":"559017034222927"},{"images":[{"height":1365,"source":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/t31.0-8\/15137528_558559867601977_1587910935337058547_o.jpg","width":2048},{"height":960,"source":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/t31.0-8\/p960x960\/15137528_558559867601977_1587910935337058547_o.jpg","width":1440},{"height":720,"source":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/t31.0-8\/p720x720\/15137528_558559867601977_1587910935337058547_o.jpg","width":1080},{"height":600,"source":"https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xtf1\/t31.0-0\/p600x600\/15137528_558559867601977_1587910935337058547_o.jpg","width":900},{"height":480,"source":"https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xtf1\/t31.0-0\/p480x480\/15137528_558559867601977_1587910935337058547_o.jpg","width":720},{"height":320,"source":"https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xtf1\/v\/t1.0-0\/q83\/p320x320\/15095087_558559867601977_1587910935337058547_n.jpg?oh=623efbdcfe8c0aaa8eb5b74b96899109&oe=58C0951B&__gda__=1488708150_691d164f5ade13aead6e70c49a89b1de","width":480},{"height":540,"source":"https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xtf1\/t31.0-0\/q83\/p180x540\/15137528_558559867601977_1587910935337058547_o.jpg","width":810},{"height":130,"source":"https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xtf1\/v\/t1.0-0\/q83\/p130x130\/15095087_558559867601977_1587910935337058547_n.jpg?oh=0b0254ba932abd5f5e1cd555d237792b&oe=5888D974&__gda__=1490327641_797338b634f0523de1bfef4bf34bfd8d","width":195},{"height":2
```

What i want is, fetch only the album name, source url of each image and created_time.

Any one can help me with this issue? 
Thanks so much! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The returned form should be JSONArray

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
```

While the returned data is JSON Object (as I can see in the error you have given).

You can use StringRequest for your purpose as:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(endpoint,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                                pDialog.hide();

                                images.clear();

         Error-Line----->       JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);             //Here you have to cast string response as JSON Object

                                JSONArray returnedData = responseObj.getJSONArray("data");

                                for (int i = 0; i < returnedData.length(); i++) {
                                    try {


                                       JSONObject object = returnedData.getJSONObject(i);
                                       Image image = new Image();

                                       JSONObject album = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                       image.setName(album.getString("name"));

                                       JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("images");
                                       image.setSmall(url.getString("source"));
                                       image.setMedium(url.getString("source"));
                                       image.setLarge(url.getString("source"));
                                       image.setTimestamp(url.getString("created_time"));

                                       images.add(image);

                                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                        Toast.makeText(PhotosActivity.this, "Erro ao carregar as fotos!! Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     }
                                 }


                                 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                 Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                                 pDialog.hide();

                        }
                   });


                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Hope it help!